# Convert HH:MM:SS in Minutes

Tags: excel, vba

How to transform dd hh:mm output only in minutes.

i.e if "dd hh:mm" is "01 10:20" I need the value only in Minutes "2060".

```
Sub ACD()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Range("C1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(TEXT(RC[-1]-NOW(),""dd hh:mm""),""00 00:00"")"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:c" & lastrow)

For b = 1 To lastrow

    b = DateDiff("n", Now(), Range("B" & b).Value)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you aware that there are 60 minutes in an hour and that a day consists of 24 hours or 1440 minutes? Do the math in VBA and you're done: `hour(someDate) * 60 + minute(someDate) + ....`.

Comment: I am new to VBA... Don't know exactly where to modify that...

Comment: Also you are trying to assign the minutes to the for loop variable. Which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ralph...I will try to fix this

Comment: @ScottCraner yes this is exactly what I need

Comment: Then it may help if you explained exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have some Time Values in Column-B(dd hh:mm).
In column-C, I took the time difference between the "Current Time" and the time value in Column-B.
All I need now is the time(in column-C) should be in Minutes instead of dd hh:mm.

Comment: Then just multiply column C (the difference between current time and column B) with 1440 and you're done. You don't even need VBA for that you can do that with a standard Excel function (possibly in column D).

Comment: @Ralph, I tried that first... its giving me "#VALUE!".
I tried this with =(Minute(C1))+(HOUR(c1)*60) also still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned, you don't really need VBA for this but something like

```
Sub ACD()      
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range("C:C")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR( ( RC[-1] - NOW() ) * 24 * 60 , 0 )"
        .NumberFormat = "0"
    End With
End Sub
```

Dates in Excel are stored as number of days, so the difference between the date in column B and the current datetime will give you a number of days like `1.43055555556`. If you multiply that by the number of hours in a day and the number of minutes in an hours (24 * 60 = 1440), you will get something like `2060.1234`. The `.NumberFormat = "0"` is used to display that difference as integer `2060`. If you want only the minutes without the seconds, you can use the `INT` or `ROUND` functions : `=IFERROR( INT( ( RC[-1] - NOW() ) * 24 * 60 ) , 0 )`

Comment: Its giving the common error "91". object variable or with block not set

Comment: ops .. I forgot `Set `

Comment: Perfect!!!!! Thanks a lot @Slai..:-) Please spare a minute to explain how it works